# how to import javascript modules from outside the main folder

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, es6-modules

I use a bunch of js libraries coded by me and stored in my computer in all my projects. Also scss files, to be true. I'd like to modify/update them in one place and then use them in all the projects I need, by importing them in main js or scss files. I used to do this with Codekit App frameworks feature.

Now for some projects I'm moving to `npm` and `webpack` and I would like to do the same. Though, can't figure out how, since it seems I cannot use absolute paths to some place in my machine when impoting js modules.

How would you solve this thing? Maybe using aliases? How to configure npm and webpack? Any idea/best practice?

Comment: 1. npm can install from a git url if you don't want to publish a package to the registry 2. if you don't want to do it the right way, you could use a symlink to put your files in any number of places on your local machine. And, not trying to be offensive, but glancing at your profile how do you not know this already? Or at least know enough to find the answer yourself without posting a question?

Comment: NPM has a thing for this, and its main use is for package developers who want to test their packages in other projects before publishing them. It looks like it fits your needs: [the `npm link` command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link). You can then require your package just like if it were published on NPM. No need for paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some solutions to what you want:

### NPM Link

You can use local NPM projects using [NPM link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link).

Imagine you have the following structure:

```
> root
 |
 | - (dep) Your custom package
 | - (cur) Your package that needs to use "dep".
```

You can run `npm link ./../dep` inside the `cur` folder to link the `dep` package. this way you can use it as if it was an NPM package from the public registry.

### Github scoped packages

You can also push you local packages to private repositories on Github, so that you can use them anywhere but are still not publicly accessible.

To do this, you can simple install them like so:

```sh
npm install git+https://github.com/your-username/your-package.git
```